# Add a new column to a dataframe based on a csv mapping (generic approach)

Tags: scala, dataframe, mapping

I have a file called zip.csv mapping file that I want to use to create a new column in a Spark dataframe based on an existing column.
This is how my mapping csv looks like

```
zip,area
ABC,Region 1
DEF,Region 2
OGE,Region 3
GRE,Region 3
```

I want to apply this mapping to a new data file that looks like this

```
zip,name,age
ABC,ERIK,23
DEF,JAN,44
OGE,OLE,21
GRE,EILI,26
ABC,EILI,33
```

applying the mapping on this will return

```
zip,name,age,area
ABC,ERIK,23,Region 1
DEF,JAN,44,Region 2
OGE,OLE,21,Region 3
GRE,EILI,26,Region 4
ABC,EILI,33,Region 1
```

At the moment I do it as follows

```
var fileName = "pathtofile/name.csv"
var nameDF = spark.read.format("csv")
                        .option("header", "true")
                        .option("delimiter", ",")
                        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                        .load(fileName)  


val fromToValue = udf {(fromValue: String) => 
  if(fromValue == "ABC") "Region 1"
  else if(fromValue == "DEF") "Region 2"
  else if(fromValue == "OGE") "Region 3"
  else if(fromValue == "GRE") "Region 4"
  else "NA"
}


nameDF = nameDF.withColumn("Area", fromToValue(nameDF("zip")))
display(nameDF)
```

This is working. But how can rewrite the user defined function fromToValue to use this csv file?

```
zip,area
ABC,Region 1
DEF,Region 2
OGE,Region 3
GRE,Region 3
```

Also I want to use this udf for similar mappings later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pattern matching for map function and udf.apply for your map function, correct example:

```
var fileName = "pathtofile/name.csv"
var nameDF = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .load(fileName)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def fromToValue(zipDictionary: Map[String, String]): String => String = zipDictionary(_)

val zipCodesDict = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .load("path_to_zip_csv")
  .collect()
  .map(r => r.getString(0) -> r.getString(1))
  .toMap

nameDF = nameDF.withColumn("Area", udf(fromToValue(zipCodesDict)).apply(col("zip")))
display(nameDF)
```

if you know some specific cases you can handle it this way:

```
def fromToValue(zipDictionary: Map[String, String]): String => String = {
    case "TYU" | "<another_case>" | "<another_one>" => "Region Unknown"
    case zip => zipDictionary(zip)
  }
```

if you don't know cases you can simple use getOrElse method:

```
def fromToValue(zipDictionary: Map[String, String]): String => String = zip => 
zipDictionary.getOrElse(zip, "Region Unknown")
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. My main goal is that if I get a new value in zip.csv (e.g."KLM"->"Region 9" I dont want to change my notebook (only modify zip.csv)

Comment: @reachify for use mapping dynamically, you can construct Map and use it for that

Comment: But dont fromToValue udf have to be modified as zipCodesDict has the values hardcoded in fromToValue.  scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(ABC -> Region 1, DEF -> Region 2, OGE -> Region 3, GRE -> Region 3)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Comment: How can I handle a zip code that does not exist in the mapping file. E.g. zip=TYU should return Region Unknown